# Negative value for saturation mode voltage of MOSFET

Tags: transistors, mosfet, saturation

I want confirmation of whether a MOSFET is in saturation or not. I have calculated the condition using the formula \$V_{GS}-V_{tn}\$, and my answer is a negative value. Does it matter if the value is negative? If yes, what is the value actually showing?

Comment: What does \$ V_{DS} - V_{tn} \$ get you? I don't think I've heard an equation that requires you to subtract the threshold voltage from the drain-source voltage. I've heard, however, of subtracting the threshold voltage from the **gate-source voltage**, thus getting the **drain-source voltage**, which can determine the FET's mode of operation. Perhaps you mean \$V_{GS} - V_{tn} \$ instead?

Comment: Did you switch channels? from N to Pch_en

Comment: yaa, it is actually Vgs not Vds, my mistake. i have edited it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If \$ V_{GS} \$ is smaller than your than your threshold, \$V_{tn}\$, then that means your FET is in **cutoff** region, meaning that your drain current \$I_D=0\$ and your FET will **not** conduct. Here's a good table from the Sedra\Smith textbook that gives a good summary of the regions of operations for the NMOS device, where \$V_{ov}\$ is the **overdrive voltage**.

[image]

Comment: tq for the answer and the reference u gave.!

Comment: You're very welcome :) glad it was a typo. It confused me at first. Just remember to add channel length modulation to the formulas if the question asks to include it. This table also neglects the Body Effect because it's a three terminal device implying that the substrate is tied to the source.

Answer (score 1):

The check for saturation has two conditions:

\$V_{GS}>V_{th}\$ and \$V_{DS}\geq V_{GS}-V_{th}\$

To rearrrange the second equation for  \$V_{GS}\$, you would get the following equation: \$V_{DS}+V_{th}\geq V_{GS}\$. If you somehow ended up with \$V_{DS}-V_{th}\$, that suggests a likely algrebra error.

If you find that \$(V_{GS}-V_{th})<0\$, then that means that you do not meet the other requirement, which is \$V_{GS}>V_{th}\$.

Your transistor is off (cutoff/subthreshold) and will be in neither linear mode or saturation mode.

Comment: yaa it is actually Vgs not Vds. tq for the answer!